# Como não perder as casas decimais ao fazer "longProperty1.divide(longProperty2)"?

Tags: java, javafx, double, binding, divisão

O que quero fazer é bem simples, só não sei como "fazer direito" no JavaFX:

Eu tenho duas [LongProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/LongProperty.html) (`num1` e `num2`) e uma [DoubleProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/DoubleProperty.html) (`resultado`), onde essa DoubleProperty `resultado` deve conter - sempre atualizado - o valor da divisão de `num1` por `num2`.

Eu já consigo fazer isso com o código `resultado.bind(num1.divide(num2));`, mas o problema é que **desse modo eu perco a precisão das casas decimais**, e eu preciso das casas decimais.

Pelo que percebi, o problema é que ao fazer `num1.divide(num2)` o método [`divide`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpression.html#divide-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-) retorna um [`LongBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/LongBinding.html) (pois as variáveis divididas são `LongProperty`s) ao invés de retornar um [`DoubleBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleBinding.html), e parece que é esse `LongBinding` que elimina as casas decimais.

Experimentei fazer `num1` e `num2` também serem `DoubleProperty`e fazer `num1.divide(num2)`; e deu certo: o método `divide` retornou um `DoubleBinding` que preservou as casas decimais no `resultado`. Mas eu quero que `num1` e `num2`sejam `LongProperty`s mesmo, então como fazer?

Eu consegui contornar o problema com uma *gambiarra* que mostra o que eu preciso:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.binding.NumberBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;

public class DoubleBindingEmDivisaoDeLong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        teste1_divisaoPerdeAsCasasDecimais();
        teste2_divisaoMantemAsCasasDecimais();
    }

    private static void teste1_divisaoPerdeAsCasasDecimais() {
        final DoubleProperty resultado = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
        final LongProperty num1 = new SimpleLongProperty(45);
        final LongProperty num2 = new SimpleLongProperty(7);
        NumberBinding divide = num1.divide(num2); // O método divide Retorna um "LongBinding" (veja a linha abaixo para confirmar)
        System.out.println(divide);// Imprime: "LongBinding [invalid]"
        resultado.bind(divide);

        System.out.println(resultado.get()); // Imprime: "6.0" ao invés de "6.428571428571429" (perdeu as casas decimais)
    }

    private static void teste2_divisaoMantemAsCasasDecimais() {
        final DoubleProperty resultado = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
        final LongProperty num1 = new SimpleLongProperty(45);
        final LongProperty num2 = new SimpleLongProperty(7);

        final DoubleProperty num1Double = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
        num1Double.bind(num1);
        final DoubleProperty num2Double = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
        num2Double.bind(num2);

        DoubleBinding divide = num1Double.divide(num2Double); // O método divide Retorna um "DoubleBinding"
        resultado.bind(divide);

        System.out.println(resultado.get()); // Imprime "6.428571428571429" como desejado
    }
}
```

Note que no código acima, o que faz funcionar no teste2 é o fato de eu ter criado `num1Double` e `num2Double` que são `DoubleProperty`s e que fazem `bind` em `num1` e `num2` respectivamente, e, ter feito algo equivalente à `resultado.bind(num1Double.divide(num2Double));`, ou seja, uma gambiarra para algo que deve ser bem simples e já previsto no JavaFX.

Então, como se faz do "jeito certo" no JavaFX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui uma boa resposta no SOen [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265814/how-to-not-lose-decimal-places-when-doing-longproperty1-dividelongproperty2/46268442#46268442) (link em inglês), segue abaixo uma tradução/adaptação dela:

> Os métodos fornecidos por `LongProperty` (e por outros [`NumberExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpression.html)) como `divide(...)` são apenas métodos de conveniência; mas você pode criar um *binding* personalizado que faça o que você quiser:
>
> ```
> final DoubleProperty result = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
> final LongProperty longProperty1 = new SimpleLongProperty(812323534);
> final LongProperty longProperty2 = new SimpleLongProperty(956745323);
> result.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> longProperty1.longValue() / (double) longProperty2.longValue(),
>     longProperty1, longProperty2));
> System.out.println(result.get());
> longProperty1.set(612323534);
> System.out.println(result.get());
> ```
>
> [Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) é uma classe utilitária para criar *bindings*. Aqui criei um binding personalizado que retorna um `double` fazendo *cast* da divisão dos `long`s para `double`, mas há perca de precisão.
>
> A saída do código acima é:
>
> ```
> 0.8490488685670847
> 0.6400068223798362
> ```

Através desta resposta, obtenho um DoubleBiding criado por [createDoubleBinding(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createDoubleBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-) que irá manter `result`sempre atualizado com o resultado da divisão de `longProperty1`por `longProperty2`.

Ou seja, quando o valor de qualquer uma destas duas variáveis for alterado (seja de `longProperty1` ou de `longProperty2`), a divisão será reprocessada automaticamente e `result`será atualizado automaticamente com o novo resultado da divisão.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
final DoubleProperty result = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
final LongProperty longProperty1 = new SimpleLongProperty(45);
final LongProperty longProperty2 = new SimpleLongProperty(7);

result.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> longProperty1.longValue() / (double) longProperty2.longValue(),
            longProperty1, longProperty2));

System.out.println(result.get()); // imprime "6.428571428571429", que é 45 dividido por 7

longProperty1.set(100); // longProperty1 agora contém o valor 100
System.out.println(result.get()); // imprime "14.285714285714286", que é 100 dividido por 7

longProperty2.set(876); // longProperty2 agora contém o valor 876
System.out.println(result.get()); // imprime "0.1141552511415525", que é 100 dividido por 876
```

Observe que as casas decimais são preservadas como eu preciso, e, mesmo que a precisão do resultado seja afetada no momento em que se faz a divisão, eu ainda consigo armazenar números gigantes (*long*) dentro de `longProperty1` e `longProperty2` sem que eles sejam afetados, não sendo necessário transformá-los em `DoubleProperty`s.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sinceramente nunca usei esta API do Java FX, mas já vivi o mesmo "problema" em diversas APIs e linguagens diferentes.

Basicamente, o que parece ocorrer é que quando você trabalha com tipos inteiros, a divisão é inteira também.

Perceba que escrevi "problema" entre aspas acima porque é mais uma característica do que um bug. Algumas linguagens ou APIs fazem o "upgrade" de inteiro para decimal automaticamente, outras não, havendo vantagens e desvantagens para cada abordagem.

No seu caso, eu diria que trocar `SimpleLongProperty` por `SimpleDoubleProperty` para suas variáveis `num1` e `num2` seria uma forma razoável de resolver o problema, no sentido de que você está normalizando as suas variáveis usando tipos decimais ao invés de misturar decimais e inteiros.

Comment: Minha resistência em trocar `num1` e `num2` para `DoubleProperty`s é porque - muito provavelmente - elas receberão números muito grandes (`long` mesmo), por isso não me é interessante nem mesmo fazer o cast delas para double. Por outro lado, `result` irá receber um valor de `0.0` atè `1.0`, porque, no meu problema real, `num1` sempre será menor ou igual à `num2`.

Comment: @Douglas Entendo sua preocupação, mas Double não é menor que Long. Ela tem uma limitação, mas em geral pode acomodar números Long sem problemas. Não chega a ser algo como o BigDecimal, que infelizmente parece não fazer parte desta API (fiz uma breve pesquisa no JavaDoc), mas deve ser suficiente para a maioria dos casos de uso.

Comment: utluiz dê uma olhada na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238140/68989) que acabei de postar (obtida do SOen), acredito que ela seja a melhor forma que o JavaFX oferece para fazer o que eu perguntei.

Comment: @Douglas Realmente não posso julgar qual seria a melhor resposta. Basicamente você está transformando suas variáveis long em double por baixo dos panos, então ela basicamente não tem diferença em termos de precisão numérica. A vantagem é que você mantém suas variáveis de entrada no tipo que você quer, a desvantagem é que seu código fica mais poluído.